# Помогите составить правильный SQL запрос с LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Задание с SQL Academy: Выведите имена first_name и фамилии last_name всех учителей из таблицы Teacher, а также количество занятий, в которых они назначены преподавателями.
Для вывода количества занятий используйте псевдоним amount_classes.

Не пойму в чем ошибка, вот мой запрос:

```
SELECT Teacher.first_name, Teacher.last_name, COUNT(Class.id) AS amount_classes
FROM Teacher
LEFT JOIN Class
ON Teacher.id = Class.id
GROUP BY Teacher.first_name, Teacher.last_name;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Teacher.first_name, Teacher.last_name, COUNT(Schedule.id) AS amount_classes
FROM Teacher
LEFT JOIN Schedule ON Teacher.id = Schedule.teacher
GROUP BY Teacher.first_name, Teacher.last_name;
```

Смотрела не в ту таблицу: присоединяла `Class`, а нужно было `Schedule`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t.first_name, t.last_name, COUNT(s.teacher) AS amount_classes
FROM Teacher AS t
LEFT JOIN Schedule AS s
ON t.id = s.teacher
GROUP BY first_name, last_name;

Comment: А чем ваше решение отличается от предложеных в ранее данных ответов?

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT 
    Teacher.first_name, 
    Teacher.last_name,
    COUNT(Schedule.teacher) as amount_classes 
FROM Teacher 
LEFT JOIN Schedule ON Teacher.id = Schedule.teacher 
GROUP BY Teacher.id;
```